# How to explain zscore?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, data-analysis, data-science

I am trying to understand the below result set.
F20 variable binned into two groups 0 and 1-722. The question I am posing here is for bin 0.
I have responders variable as population1 and non-responders variable as population2.
I also have %proportion for responders and non responders.
INDEX is in % too and is the proportion of responders/proportion non-responders.
When I calculated the zscore I got -9.38. Index shows 99 which means ratio of the proportion for both population is very similar yet the zscore is so high.
Can anyone explain me please. Forgive me for my little statistics knowledge.

[image]

Comment: This question is better suited for Cross Validated as it has to do with stats and not programming. How did you calcuate your Z-score?

Comment: Hi emilliman5, N1=population1, N2=population2, P1 = proportion1 and P2=proportion2 and the formula is as follows:                                                                                                                     P = ((P1*N1)+(P2*N2))/(N1+N2);
PP = ((1/N1)+(1/N2));
SE = SQRT(P*(1-P)*PP);
ZSCORE = (P1-P2)/SE;

Answer (score 0):

Sure you have the right formula? Try this:

```
z.prop = function(x1,x2,n1,n2){
  numerator = (x1/n1) - (x2/n2)
  p.common = (x1+x2) / (n1+n2)
  denominator = sqrt(p.common * (1-p.common) * (1/n1 + 1/n2))
  z.prop.ris = numerator / denominator
  return(z.prop.ris)
}

z.prop(1, 0.98499, 19187, 18735)
# -0.006139796
```

PS:  maybe go with a chi-square test instead, since your proportions are so skewed.
[Source](http://statistic-on-air.blogspot.com/2009/07/comparison-of-two-proportions.html)

Comment: Hi ddunn801, thank you so much. May be you right! My formula for pooled proportion calculation may not be correct one. Let me test yours. Thank you though